# How to detach an attribute from a class?

Tags: python

Having a class `C` with an attribute `coordinates`.

```
class C():
   def __init__():
      self.coordinates=[]

c = C()
coords = c.coordinates
```

if I change now `coords`, I would like to change it only "local", so I would like to detach `coords` from `C`, so that `c.coordinates` isn't changed.

Is there a better way than

```
coords_ = coords[:]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with classes and attributes. This is how references to *any* list works. `a = []; b = a` has the same effect.

Comment: `coords = coords[:]` is how I'd write it (no need to create a new variable name).  `coords = coords.copy()` might be a bit clearer.

Comment: Using `coords[:]` is the simplest way to make a copy of the list.

Comment: beware that `coords[:]` makes a shallow copy of `coords`